# React native check if a passed parameter is a valid color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wrote a method I use to check if the value passed is a color I can use for `LinearGradient`.

On LinearGradient I can only use a color `array> = 2` colors and not a string that identifies the example color `"#ccc"`.

The there are some times when it does not work the cases are:

When a string of this type is passed
`rgb (255, 0, 0)` or `rgb (255, 0, 0, 1)`

So I have to create a function that checks if it's a color:

```
#ccc
#cccccc
rgb (255, 0, 0)
rgba (255, 0, 0, 1)
```

And a function that checks if the variable passed is an array, if it is not contains a valid value for a color, I create an array with a duplicate of the value.

Code:

```
   _backgroundColor = color => {
        if (
          !Array.isArray(color) &&
          !/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(color)
        )
          color = '#1e95cc';

        if (Array.isArray(color) && color.length < 2) color = color.concat(color);
        else if (!Array.isArray(color)) color = [color, color];

        return color;
      };
```